# Saving an image into user model

Tags: python, django, imagefield

I'm trying to make an "avatar" field in my user model (tried using all libraries out there, didnt quite like them)

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
...
pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos", default='pic')
```

in setting.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'
```

Also **I'm not even using a form but uploading directly from the admin**, the problem is that the image does not save into the folder templates/media/photos.

Also I dont have any view associated, just trying the image to save into the folder so I can understand better how the file system works.

edit: misspelled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your settings to serve static media properly when using a local environment.

**Add this to your settings.py**

```
DEBUG = True

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**Add this to your ROOT urls.py**

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: "NameError: name 'static' is not defined"

Comment: I just added  the `settings.py` configuration that should resolve that error.

Comment: It doesnt, must be missing something really obvious, but I dont seem to get it :(

Comment: Oh my mistake, add `from django.conf.urls.static import static` into the `urls.py` (I'll edit the settings I posted to reflect this)

Comment: It now compiles, but still doesnt save the image into the folder, therefore the url still throws a 404

Comment: Did you add `DEBUG = True` into your `settings.py`? It needs to be enabled for my code to  work - also, I edited my code for BASE_DIR to work for you (mine was in another folder so it was different). Use the new `settings.py` that I included, and it should work for you

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how your MEDIA_URL looks like but the media settings should look like something like this:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

and no, you do not save media files under `templates` folder. this does not make any sense. `templates` should have html files, `static` should have static files (css, js, static images) and `media` user uploaded files.

this way, if someone joins your project or your project gets bigger, you dont end up in chaos/misleading folder names, otherwise it really hurts, believe me

**For 404 issue**:

you need change your main urls.py in root to include this:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
       url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
       {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
)
```

Comment: I actually misspelled, thanks for pointing that out. when I try to go to the URL of the image it throws a 404 at http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/photos/image.JPG

Comment: @NicolásCurti please see my update in the answer above

Comment: where do I import 'patterns' from?